# Typescript subtract two boolean

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array :

```
main = [{
           data: x,
           numberField:  1;
 }, {      data: y,
           numberField:  2;
 }, {      data: x,
           numberField:  3;
 },
  {        data:z
           numberField:  4;
 },
    {      data: q
           numberField:  5;
 }]
fixedElements = [ 3, 5]
```

I need to have :

```
 fixedElements .includes(a.numberField) - fixedElements .includes(b.numberField)
```

Because I need to check whether two coming values are in the array a and not sort them, but sort the rest.
when I try to do this typescript throws an error

```
  left/right hand-side of the argument needs to be of type any or number.
```

My initial sort function as :

```
  sort(a,b) {
  if(a.numberField > b.numberField)
       return -1

  if(a.numberField < b.numberField)
     return 1;

    }
```

So I wanted to check whether the coming a or b are in the fixedElements array, and leave them last. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: the order to be : 3, 5 to be last, and the first ones in decreasing order.

`4, 2, 1 , 3, 5`

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the booleans to numbers by using the `+` sign ([typescript playground demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20a%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(%2Ba%20-%20%2Bb)%3B)):

```
+fixedElements.includes(a.numberField) - +fixedElements.includes(b.numberField)`
```

And this is the sort logic ([typescript playgroud](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20main%20%3D%20%5B%7B%22data%22%3A%22x%22%2C%22numberField%22%3A1%7D%2C%7B%22data%22%3A%22y%22%2C%22numberField%22%3A2%7D%2C%7B%22data%22%3A%22x%22%2C%22numberField%22%3A3%7D%2C%7B%22data%22%3A%22z%22%2C%22numberField%22%3A4%7D%2C%7B%22data%22%3A%22q%22%2C%22numberField%22%3A5%7D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I'm%20using%20a%20Set%20instead%20of%20an%20array%2C%20because%20Set.has%20is%20faster%20than%20Array.includes%0D%0Aconst%20fixedElements%20%3D%20new%20Set(%5B3%2C%205%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0Amain.sort((a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20aF%20%3D%20fixedElements.has(a.numberField)%0D%0A%20%20const%20bF%20%3D%20fixedElements.has(b.numberField)%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20if(!aF%20%26%26%20!bF)%20return%20b.numberField%20-%20a.numberField%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20return%20%2BaF%20-%20%2BbF%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(main)) - check console):

```js
const main = [{"data":"x","numberField":1},{"data":"y","numberField":2},{"data":"x","numberField":3},{"data":"z","numberField":4},{"data":"q","numberField":5}]

// I'm using a Set instead of an array, because Set.has is faster than Array.includes
const fixedElements = new Set([3, 5])

main.sort((a, b) => {
  const aF = fixedElements.has(a.numberField)
  const bF = fixedElements.has(b.numberField)
  
  if(!aF && !bF) return b.numberField - a.numberField
  
  return +aF - +bF
})

console.log(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom sort function and check if the `numberField` value exists in the `fixedElements` array and leave them unsorted, otherwise sort them based on the `numberField` value.

```js
let main = [{ data: 'x', numberField: 1}, { data: 'y', numberField: 2}, { data: 'x', numberField: 3}, { data:'z', numberField: 4}, { data: 'q', numberField: 5}], 
      fixedElements = [3, 5];
main.sort((a,b) => {
  if([a,b].some(({numberField}) => fixedElements.includes(numberField)))
   return +fixedElements.includes(a.numberField) - +fixedElements.includes(b.numberField);
  else
    return +b.numberField - +a.numberField
});
console.log(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method inside of [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

```js
var array = [{
    data: 'x',
    numberField: 1
  }, {
    data: 'y',
    numberField: 2
  }, {
    data: 'x',
    numberField: 3
  }, {
    data: 'z',
    numberField: 4
  }, {
    data: 'q',
    numberField: 5
  }],
  fixedElements = [3, 5];

array.sort((a, b) => {
  a = +a.numberField;
  b = +b.numberField;
  return (fixedElements.includes(a) - fixedElements.includes(b) || b - a);
});

console.log(array)
```